# Re-resolving angular route data and keeping data in sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I'm building an angular application that repeats a set of items in a table, with the functionality to edit them inline directly inside the table. The data is fetched from a HTTP API which is handled by a service that makes the call and passes the data to wherever it was injected.

**The problem is that when an item is modified, i want to rerun the current route's resolve-functions and update the set of items. But when i do, the newly updated data is indeed fetched from the API but not updated in the view.** I suspecting i'm loosing the reference to the original array or something.

Currently we are solving this by using `$state.reload()` when an item has been updated, which reinitializes the controllers and therefore reseting things like current pagination page and/or name search fields.

A simplified version of my config and controller follows:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard.itemList', {
    url: '/items',
    controller: 'fooController',
    resolve: {
      items: ['$q', 'dataService', 'spinner', function($q, dataService, spinner) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          spinner.start();

          // Resolves an array of objects from the server
          dataService.getItems().then(function(allItems) {
            spinner.stop();
            resolve(allItems);
          }, function(error) {
            spinner.stop();
            reject(error);
          });
        });
      }]
    }
  })
});

angular.module('myModule').controller('fooController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.inlineEdit = function(item) {
    // Call the PUT-method on the API to modify an item
    apiService.update(item).then(function() {
      // Reload the data on successful update
      $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
        reload: true,
        inherit: false,
        notify: false
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Am i on the wrong track? Is it any better solution to my case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this? I've added return statements to your resolve and reject scenarios and took my preferred approach of resolving promises:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard.itemList', {
    url: '/items',
    controller: 'fooController',
    resolve: {
      items: ['$q', 'dataService', 'spinner', function($q, dataService, spinner) {
        spinner.start();
        // Resolves an array of objects from the server
        return dataService.getItems().then(function(allItems) {
            spinner.stop();
            return $q.resolve(allItems);
        }, function(error) {
            spinner.stop();
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
      }]
    }
  })
});

angular.module('myModule').controller('fooController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.inlineEdit = function(item) {
    // Call the PUT-method on the API to modify an item
    $q.when(apiService.update(item)).then(function() {
      // Reload the data on successful update
      $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
        reload: true,
        inherit: false,
        notify: false
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try wrapping your return into its own function.  This will prevent any caching of that `$q` object.

```
resolve: {
  items: function() {
    return invokeTheQStuff() 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by storing the fetched array in a variable in the dataService, which gets repopulated with the `angular.copy` method when new data is fetched. A separate reference to the array is passed in the service, which is now in sync all the time!

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard.itemList', {
    url: '/items',
    controller: 'fooController',
    resolve: {
      items: ['$q', 'dataService', 'spinner', function($q, dataService, spinner) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          spinner.start();

          // Resolves an array of objects from the server
          dataService.getItems().then(function() {
            spinner.stop();
            resolve(dataService.items);
          }, function(error) {
            spinner.stop();
            reject(error);
          });
        });
      }]
    }
  })
});

angular.module('myModule').controller('fooController', function($scope, items, spinner) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.inlineEdit = function(item) {
    // Call the PUT-method on the API to modify an item
    spinner.start();
    apiService.update(item).then(function() {
      spinner.stop();
    });
  }
});

angular.module('myModule').service('dataService', function(apiService) {
  var items = [];
  var getItems = function() {
    apiService.get('items').then(function(itemsFromApi) {
      // Instead of resolving a promise with the result, im just setting the items array here instead
      items = angular.copy(itemsFromApi, items);
    })
  };

  return {
    getItems: getItems,
    items: items
  };
});
```